# Should I use css for _escaped_fragment_ pages?

Tags: css, pagerank

I'm in the process of making an ajax site crawlable. Most of the style is generated with javascript. Do I need to even include static css in the _escaped_fragment_ pages, which should never be reached by actual visitors? Would it have any effect on page rankings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Google's own docs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/common-mistakes/blocked-resources?hl=en), for optimal SEO you need to include all CSS, JS, and images in the page the googlebot visits.